# Positive-definite function for bit-strings

Tags: functional-analysis, positive-definite

For any two $d$-bit strings $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in \{0,1\}^d$, define
$$ k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d \mathbb{1}[x_i = y_i]. $$

Is $k(\cdot, \cdot)$ a kernel (i.e., positive-definite function)?

Comment: Yes. This is just $\frac{1}{d}$ times the usual inner product of $x$ and $y$ interpreted as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Not exactly, right? Suppose $\mathbf{x}=[1, 0, 1]$, then $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) = 1$ but $\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{x} = 2$...

Comment: A modification of Qiaochu Yuan's suggestion works if you map the bit $0$ to the vector $(1,0)\in \mathbb R^2$ and the bit $1$ to the vector $(0,1)\in \mathbb R^2$ and the bit vector $[1,0,1]$ to the vector of reals $(0,1,1,0,0,1)$ this way.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misunderstood your notation.